# TrimStrings middleware keeps trimming even if attribute is in excluded array

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to exclude a json attribute from being trimmed by Laravel middleware `TrimStrings`, but it seems impossible.

The data I'm posting:

```
{
    data1: { name: "pong " },
    data2: "pang ",
}
```

In `TrimStrings` middleware I have added these attributes to excluded array:

```
protected $except = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
    'data1',
    'data2',
];
```

After middleware has ran I get:

```
$request->data1; // [ name => "pong" ]
$request->data2; // "pang "
```

The `data2` is not trimmed as expected. 
But I don't know why it trims the `data1`. I really want to keep the space.

The only way I found that keeps it from trimming is removing `TrimStrings` middleware from `kernel.php`. But it would be nice to keep `TrimStrings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see your `data2` result is correct because your parameter is `data2` and  the value is ignored for trimming, while in `data1` it is a json object, so you should put `data1.name` in the except array to ignore it.

Comment: ah that works! :)  do you know if there's a way to exclude every value in the json object?

Comment: hm, not sure about that. Haven't tried but maybe `data1.*` would work. But really not sure about that.

Answer (score 4):

@nakov answer is right, laravel uses the dot notation to parse the request data.

To avoid "nested" fields to be trimed, I had to modify the middleware like so:

```php
class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        // Abort on "nested json data"
        foreach ($this->except as $k) {
            if (str_ends_with($k, '.*') && str_starts_with($key, substr($k, 0, -2))) {
                return $value;
            }
        }

        return parent::transform($key, $value);
    }

    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        // Here you can now add your field name using the `.*` expression
        'your_field_name.*',
    ];
}
```